# Retrieve column slices from a NumPy array using variables as the indexer

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

Say I have an array and I want a function to select some of its columns based on an argument `a` that is pre-defined :

```
extracted_columns = array[:,a].
```

If I have e.g. `a = np.arange(10)`, I'll get the first ten columns,

What if I want to define a so that all the columns are selected without knowing the size of the array ?

I'd like to set `a = :` so that the function does

```
extracted_columns = array[:,:]
```

but it seems : can't pas passed as an argument. I also tried `a = None` but this gives me an array of dimensions `3` with the second dimension equal to `1`.

Is there a nice way of doing it ?

Thanks,

Comment: `a = slice(None)`

Comment: for future reference, those "two dots" are called a "colon"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a `slice` object to your function.

MCVE:

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)

print(x)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

a = slice(None)

print(x[:, a])
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

---

For your case, you'd define a function along these lines:

```
def foo(array, a):
    return array[:, a]
```

And call it like this:

```
arr_slice = foo(array, slice(None))
```

Comment: Just for future reference: `A:B` == `slice(A, B)` and `A:B:C` == `slice(A, B, C)` where A, B left empty mean `None` in `slice`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I didn't know the type slice.
Thanks !